# Использование BufferedReader в Java

Tags: java

Изучаю Java. В литературе и на многих ресурсах пишется, что использование буферезированного ввода данных является наиболее эффективным, с точки зрения производительности. Но нигде не говорится, за счет чего достигается эта эффективность.

Может кто нибудь просвятить по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы используете `BufferedReader`, вы делаете меньше запросов к нижележащему `Reader`, а он в свою очередь делает меньше запросов к `InputStream`.

К примеру, вы считываете файл посимвольно. Для каждого символа ваш `Reader` будет вызывать метод `read` на `FileInputStream`, а он в свою очередь будет вызывать низкоуровневую функцию операционной системы, которая запросит информацию в драйвера, а он запустит перемещение головки жёсткого диска и непосредственно само чтение. И так для каждого символа.

Но если вы используете `BufferedReader`, то он сразу считает 8кб (дефолтный размер буффера) в память, и дальше посимвольное чтение не будет вызывать длинную цепочку вызовов вплоть до физического чтения с диска.

Естественно, если вы считываете данные большими кусками, то `BufferedReader` никак не ускорит это.

На самом деле все гораздо сложнее, ведь ОС или драйвер сами могут буфферизировать прочитанные данные, но вы не можете знать наверняка, как работает конкретный `InputStream`, и есть ли в него какой-то внутренний буффер.

Comment: `Естественно, если вы считываете данные большими кусками` чем, если не BufferedReader? Получается есть более быстрый метод считывания? И как еще BufferedReader работает с консолью (В чем отличие от Scanner?). Если не сложно...

Comment: @ВалерійГрузицький это популярное заблуждение, что `BufferedReader` всегда ускоряет чтение. Если вы читаете файл огромными порциями, например по 1 Мб, то вы не заметите разницы. А если говорить более точно, то такое чтение будет немного медленнее, чем с обычным `Reader`-ом (лишние вызовы функций, циклы, копирования байт и т. д.). Более быстрого метода не существует. Про консоль не могу ответить